# Svelte component inside another component and share props between

Tags: svelte, svelte-3, svelte-component

I want ask you how I can use [Svelecte](https://github.com/mskocik/svelecte) inside my component and forward all props and get all events to the parent.

My case:

**App.Svelte**

```
<script>
import Select from './Select.svelte';

const list = [{ id: 1, name: 'Item 1' }, { id: 2, name: 'Item 2'}];
let myValue = null;
</script>

<h3>Select</h3>
<Select options={list} bind:value={myValue} label="Country"></Select>
<pre>{myValue}</pre>
```

**Select.svelte**

```
<script>
    import Svelecte from 'svelecte';

    export let label;
    let id = (Math.random() + 1).toString(36).substring(7);
</script>

<label for="{id}">{label}</label>
<Svelecte {...$$props} inputId={id}></Svelecte>
```

Binding in this case not working. Can you help me how I can use my own component including other component from other developer and forward props and get all events from there? I need selected item after select and get data to `App.Svelte`.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if you pass on the props like `{...$$props}` you lose the binding. From the docs

> $$props references all props that are passed to a component, including ones that are not declared with export. **It is not generally recommended**, as it is difficult for Svelte to optimise. But it can be useful in rare cases – for example, when you don't know at compile time what props might be passed to a component.

Simply export options and value and pass them declared and it seems to work [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/aceee7dcf157401e8fe52846127aa134?version=3.46.4)

```
<script>
import Select from './Select.svelte';

const list = [{ id: 1, name: 'Item 1' }, { id: 2, name: 'Item 2'}];
let myValue = null;
</script>

<h3>Select</h3>
<Select options={list} bind:value={myValue} label="Country"></Select>
<pre>{myValue}</pre>
```

###### Select.svelte

```
<script>
    import Svelecte from 'svelecte';

    export let label, options, value
        
    let id = (Math.random() + 1).toString(36).substring(7);
</script>

<label for="{id}">{label}</label>
<Svelecte {options} bind:value inputId={id}></Svelecte>
```

Comment: Great! ;) If your problem is solved then, it's best you mark your question as answered